# :action/* element is giving missing controller error

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

```
<?php
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
* ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
*/
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
Router::connect('/blog/:action/*', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' =>'index'));
/**
* Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
* how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
*/
CakePlugin::routes();

/**
* Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
* the built-in default routes.
*/
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
?>
```

here is my route.php file when i try to access website/blog it would throw me an error saying blog controller is missing.
but when i change "/blog/:action/*" to "/blog" it wil work fine what am i doing wrong ??
please help thanks.

Comment: you need to describe your problem better. ok, "blog/:action/*" doesn't work and "/blog" does... so why don't you leave it like "/blog"? If you don't tell us what you want to do, then the obvious answer will be "put /blog and that works"

Comment: sorry for that actually i am new to cakephp so sorry if i did not explain well. Actually what i am trying to do is map the  **"Items"** (which is a controller in my application) to **"/blog"** so when i enter **website/blog** it redirect me to **website/Item/index**
and when i enter **website/Items/view/1** it redirects me to **website/blog/View/1**

Comment: It is just basic cakePhp.I dont why it is not working with :action element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on your comments, try this

```
//redirects "website/items/view/1" to "website/blogs/view/1"
Router::connect('/items/:action/*', array('controller' => 'blogs'));

//redirects "/blog" to "website/items/index"
Router::connect('/blog', array('controller' => 'items', 'action' =>'index'));
```

But it seems awfully confusing? why redirect blog to items (*"website/blog it redirect me to website/Item/index"*) and items to blog (*"website/Items/view/1 it redirects me to website/blog/View/1"*)? Shouldn't you just change those actions to the controller where you want to have them?

And please read the [routing docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes).

Comment: Thank you @nunser 
sorry for confusion its my first post so i hope i will be better next time Thank you again for quick help

Comment: @user2867340 No problem :) For next questions, try to explain your problem with full detail *in the question itself, not the comments*. Here's a link that can help you, [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And also, do your research first and explain in the question what you have tried and why it didn't work. And grammar is important!! A well formatted question will probably get you better answers faster.